# VBA pass windows authentication to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, vba

I have a VBA project that uploads data from an Excel spreadsheet to an Access database stored on SharePoint.  All was well until I upgraded to Windows 7.  Windows 7 doesn't automatically pass Windows authentication to SharePoint when accessed this way.  Now my project will not update my db.  How can I get my VBA project to pass that information to SharePoint?  I've been searching for 2 days and I haven't found anything helpful.

Comment: Not sure if you are looking for this? http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/hack-windows-authentication-for-your-applications/ I have never worked with Sharepoint before...

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work in my situation.  That trick is to test to see if someone has access to SharePoint.  My code can't access SharePoint since vba in Windows 7 doesn't automatically transmit that info.

Comment: If you got a solution can you help me ... i am stuck at same place

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem today. The workaround I came up with, which I would love to replace, is to force Windows Explorer to open the sharepoint folder, which triggers the authentication request to the user. Obviously, there are many issues with this solution.